# How do I force the scroll position on a fixed div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

In a fixed div with absolute positioning, how can I set the scroll position using JavaScript.

I'm trying to use `scrollTop` to set the location but the content div does not have a height explicitly set which I believe key here.

A mockup of my layout is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rzD82/2/).

Does anyone have a workaround to this or do I need to change my layout approach?

Comment: Why haven't you accepted my answer? Did you notice that once you fixed your fiddle per my suggestion, it started working?

Comment: Actually my error in dev was something slightly different but I've marked it as the answer because you pointed me in the right direction. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have this:

```
<div id="#content" class="content">
```

When you should have this:

```
<div id="content" class="content">
```